# Remove entries from the list using iterator

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I need to write a simple function that will delete all entries in the `List` that contains objects of the class `Elem`. I wrote the function `removeAllElements`, but it does not work if the size of the `List<Elem>` is greater than 1.

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Work w = new Work();
        w.addElement(new Elem("a",new Integer[]{1,2,3}));
        w.addElement(new Elem("b",new Integer[]{4,5,6}));

        w.removeAllElements(); // It does not work for me.
    }
}    

public class Work {

    private List<Elem> elements = new ArrayList<Elem>();

    public void addElement(Elem e) {
        this.elements.add(e);
    }

    public void removeAllElements() {
        Iterator itr = this.elements.iterator(); 
        while(itr.hasNext()) {
            Object e = itr.next();
            this.elements.remove(e);
        }
    }

}

public class Elem {

    private String title;
    private Integer[] values;

    public Elem(String t,Integer v) {
        this.title = t;
        this.values = v;
    }

}
```

**Edit#1**
The error message is the following:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The code doesn't compile. What is `this.tokens`?

Anyway, if you want to remove an element while iterating, you must do it using the iterator's remove method:

```
itr.next();
itr.remove();
```

Your `removeAllElements` method could just do `this.elements.clear()`, though. Much more straightforward and efficient.

Answer (score 6):

You must use `itr.remove()` and not `this.tokens.remove(e)` while removing elements while iterating.

For more details, look at [Iterator.remove()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29)

Comment: Then it says: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException
 at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.remove(Unknown Source)
 at cpn_logic.Work.removeAllElements(Work.java:119)

Comment: @KlausosKlausos: You need to use `remove()` only after you used `next()`, as the javadocs I linked to clearly indicate.

Comment: Not just *should*, you **must**

Comment: Oh, I had to use itr.next() and the itr.remove()

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that `tokens` is your Arraylist?

When removing elements dynamically from an array list, you need to use the [.remove](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29) method provided by the iterator. So you need to do something like this:

```
public void removeAllElements() {
        Iterator itr = this.elements.iterator(); 
        while(itr.hasNext()) {
            Object e = itr.next();
            itr.remove();
        }
    }
```

If you want to just remove all the elements from the list, you can call the [.clear](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clear%28%29) method of the Arraylist:

> Removes all of the elements from this list. The list will be empty
>   after this call returns.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the iterator's "remove" method: http://www.java-examples.com/remove-element-collection-using-java-iterator-example.