# How to remove from a set

Tags: java, iterator, set

This method accepts a set of strings and then removes all strings of even length of the set.
The problem is that I know that sets do not count by elements so I have to us an iterator, however, how do I delete a specific "element" from a set?

```
private static void removeEvenLength(Set<String> thing) {
    Iterator<String> stuff = thing.iterator();

    while (stuff.hasNext()) {
        String temp = stuff.next();
        if (temp.length() %2 == 0) {
            temp.remove(); // What do I do here?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove entries from the list using iterator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892027/remove-entries-from-the-list-using-iterator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private static void removeEvenLength(Set<String> thing) {
        thing.add("hi"); 
        thing.add("hello");
          Iterator<String> stuff = thing.iterator();
          System.out.println("set"+thing);
            while (stuff.hasNext()) {
                String temp = stuff.next();
                if (temp.length() %2 == 0) {
                    stuff.remove(); 
                }
            }
            System.out.println("set"+thing); 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

try using iterator

```
 stuff.remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8, you could try something like this:

```
public static void removeEvenLength(final Set<String> set){
    set.stream().filter(string -> string.length() % 2 == 0).forEach(set::remove);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do that as the Set class is fast-fail throwing ConcurrentModificationException as you are trying to remove an element from the set without using the iterator.