# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in processing

Tags: java, arrays, processing, indexoutofboundsexception

So I've been working on a small tanks program, but whenever I try to run it I get an ArrayIndexOutOf BoundsException on line 477 (http://pastebin.com/k4WNXE6Q).

```
void placeStations(int Number) {
  for (int i = 0; i<Number; i++) {
    stations.add(new RefillStation(int(random(0, width)), int(random(0, height))));

    // This line of code refuses to work. I get an 'ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -3'
    RefillStation station = stations.get(i);

    for (Tank tank : tanks) {
      if (station.getRectangle().intersects(tank.getRectangle())) {
        station.kill();
        i=i-1;
      }
    }
    for (Obstacle obstacle : obstacles) {
      if (station.getRectangle().intersects(obstacle.getRectangle())) {
        station.kill();
        i=i-1;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried for hours to find an error, but I can see nothing different from the method above, which seems to work fine. I am using the 'i' type for loops in some places because whenever I try to remove something from an index in a modern for loop, it gives me a size change exception. Any Ideas on what I could do to remedy this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple overlaps with Tanks and Obstacles will cause i to be reduced repeatedly. But you want to kill the station only once: break out of the loop.

```
 for (Tank tank : tanks) {
   if (station.getRectangle().intersects(tank.getRectangle())) {
     station.kill();
     i=i-1;
     break;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

for(each) style loops use iterators under the hood and most of the time you can't edit a collection that you're iterating over other than through the `remove()` method of the iterator object. To do that you'll have to use the iterator explicitly. see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892027/remove-entries-from-the-list-using-iterator)

btw variable names with an upper case first character work, but makes it harder for people to read and understand your code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the issue but isn't ArrayList is supposed to have 1st argument for index and second one for the element:

public void add(int index,
       E element)
 And your code is :

```
stations.add(new RefillStation(int(random(0, width)), int(random(0, height))));
```

It is adding element first and then specifying the index.