# How to delete last x element of a list after performing some operation on them?

Tags: java

i know how to iterate the last n element of a list using :

```
for(int i = list.size()-1; i>elements ; i --)
{
   list.element.get(i).makeSomeStuff();
   list.remove(list.element.get(i));
}
```

but i need to remove the elements from the list safely without messing around with the index

Comment: Hi, does your posted code compiles? What is `list.element`? Shouldn't it be just `list` if it is plain `java.util.List`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to create a secondary list to hold the objects that you want to delete from the originating list.

```
List<MyObject> toBeRemovedList = new ArrayList()<>;
for(int i = list.size()-1; i>elements ; i --)
{
    MyObject myObject = list.get(i);
    myObject.makeSomeStuff();  //perform object action
    toBeRemovedList.add(myObject); //add the object into the removal list
}

list.removeAll(toBeRemovedList); //remove all the elements of the removal list from the originating list, no index interfering
```

Comment: why are you using a separate list `toBeRemovedList`?,  we can directly delete from the list right. it won't effect anything

Comment: @Mahesh Yes it seems not to affect anything (since items from the end of the list are getting removed), that's what the original author is doing in his code, but it is not a good idea to remove elements while looping on a list.

Answer (score 1):

Use an Iterator instead of an indexed `for` loop if you need to remove elements from the collection (List in your case). See [Remove entries from the list using iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892027/remove-entries-from-the-list-using-iterator)