# How can I make this for loop repeatedly go through a list of arrays until a condition is reached?

Tags: java

I have this method that searches a list of arrays of type Person and deletes a specific one based on the first name.

It works fine.

But it only deletes one person and then stops.

```
        public void deleteFriend(String firstName){
                Person friendToDelete = null;
                for(Person f : friendsList){
                    if(f.getFirstName().equalsIgnoreCase(firstName)){
                        friendToDelete = f;
                    }
                }
                if(friendToDelete != null){
                    friendsList.remove(friendToDelete);
                    System.out.println("Friend deleted.");
                }
        }
```

Say my list `friendsList` has two people with the first name `Shane`. I want my method to delete ***all** Shanes*.

---

I have tried the following:

```
    public void deleteFriend(String firstName){
        //Person friendToDelete = null;
        for(Person f : friendsList){
            if(f.getFirstName().equalsIgnoreCase(firstName)){
                friendsList.remove(f);
                continue; 
            }
        }
    }
```

In the above example, I tried some variations of the `if` loop. First, I tried `break;` instead of `continue;`. I also tried removing that line altogether.

```
if(f.getFirstName().equalsIgnoreCase(firstName))
                friendsList.remove(f);
```

It still **only deleted the first** Shane.

I tried to make a condition to check if there are instances of `Person` with the first name `Shane` and while that is true, go through the list with `for(Person f : friendsList)` and remove it. And then check if there still is a Shane, and do it again.

But I can tell that what I have isn't going to work:

```
        public void deleteFriend(String firstName){
                //Person friendToDelete = null;
                for(Person f : friendsList){
                    int cond = 0;
                    while(cond == 0){
                        if(f.getFirstName().equalsIgnoreCase(firstName)){
                            friendsList.remove(f);
                        }
                        else{
                            // ??? cond = 1?
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
```

Can someone help me with what I'm trying to do or point me in the right direction?

Comment: RemoveAll method https://howtodoinjava.com/java/collections/arraylist/arraylist-removeall/ might be helpful

Comment: See the old fashioned way https://stackoverflow.com/a/8892090/2310289

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Java 8 method [`Collection.removeIf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf(java.util.function.Predicate)), expecting a `Predicate`, to do so and make your code waaaaay simpler.

To perform a delete operation in a list based on a certain condition, just do:

```
friendsList.removeIf(p -> p.getFirstName().equalsIgnoreCase(firstName));
```

Here is a bit of more on it: [Operating and Removing an Item - Collection.removeIf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf(java.util.function.Predicate))

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to iterate over the friends list using indexing like so:

```java
int index = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < friendsList.length; i++) {
    if(!friendsList[i].getFirstName().equalsIgnoreCase(firstName)) {
        friendsList[index++] = friendsList[i];
    }
}

return Arrays.copyOf(friendsList, index);
```

As seen in this [Geeks for Geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/remove-all-occurrences-of-an-element-from-array-in-java/) page. Check it out for other options, like filtering your list (which is much simpler & quicker).